# How to Google Chrome Cast music in the background on iOS device?

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

I have a music player application into which I have implemented the iOS Google Cast SDK.

I've got everything working while running the app (connecting to cast device, streaming music, next/prev song control, volume control, seek control).

Once I put the application in the BG and click to the next song, it looks like the connection to the cast receiver device is lost. The receiver continues playing the song until the end and then just sits there.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can enable cast controls while the application is running in BG? I've seen it done by Google Play Music iOS App but  can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a solution by digging through the GCKDeviceManager Class Reference on the Google Cast documentation website...

If you would like your GCKDeviceManager to ignore Application state change, you need to initiate your GCKDeviceManager so...

```
self.chromeCastDeviceManager = [[GCKDeviceManager alloc] initWithDevice:self.selectedChromeCastDevice clientPackageName:[info objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"] ignoreAppStateNotifications:YES];
```

Setting **ignoreAppStateNotifications** to **YES** will not disconnect your Google Cast connection when the application goes to BG.

I wish they would mention this in the iOS section of the site, could have saved me a day of looking around.

Comment: Since GCKDeviceManager is deprecated in v3 of the Cast library, the flag has moved to GCKCastOptions which is used to initialize the cast context. It's now called suspendSessionsWhenBackgrounded

Comment: @buddahbrot Were you guys able to play songs continuously in background with the help of these flags?
Because for me, it throws session suspended due to network not being reachable after a while when app is in background.

Answer (score -1):

You should really refer to the Google [docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender) about Chromecast integration with iOS apps.

Comment: I cant find anything on that site about handling background controls